# How to write a file based on eventReactive

Tags: r, csv, shiny

My app allows the user to generate some plots and save them as png.

I want the app as well to update a csv file based on some inputs made into the app by the user.

For example purposes, I created a toy app that generates a csv file in a given folder.

In both cases, the app doesn't display any error message or info, but it doesn't store any file anywhere.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(AlphaPart)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("var1","Select var1", choices = names(iris)),
  selectInput("var2","Select var2", choices = names(iris)),
  plotOutput("myplot"),
  downloadLink("downloadPlot", label = icon("download")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- reactive(iris)
  var1 <- reactive({input$var1})
  var2 <- reactive({input$var2})
  
  # Genearte plot
  draw_boxplot <- function(data, var1, var2){
    ggplot(data=data(), aes(x=.data[[input$var1]], y = .data[[input$var2]]))+
      geom_boxplot() 
  }
  
  plot1 <- reactive({
    req(data(), input$var1, input$var2)
    draw_boxplot(data(), var1(), var2())
  })
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    plot1()
  })
  
  #Download
  output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      return("Plot.png")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      png(file)
      print(plot1())
      dev.off()
    })
  
  #Write csv
  
  eventReactive(input$downloadPlot, {
    dat <- as.data.frame(c(input$num_var_1, input$num_var_2))
    write.csv(dat, "C:/dat.csv", row.names = FALSE)
  })
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(AlphaPart)
library(spsComps)


ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput("var1","Select var1", choices = names(iris)),
    selectInput("var2","Select var2", choices = names(iris)),
    plotOutput("myplot"),
    downloadLink("downloadPlot", label = icon("download")))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    data <- reactive(iris)
    var1 <- reactive({input$var1})
    var2 <- reactive({input$var2})
    
    # Genearte plot
    draw_boxplot <- function(data, var1, var2){
        ggplot(data=data(), aes(x=.data[[input$var1]], y = .data[[input$var2]]))+
            geom_boxplot() 
    }
    
    plot1 <- reactive({
        req(data(), input$var1, input$var2)
        draw_boxplot(data(), var1(), var2())
    })
    
    output$myplot <- renderPlot({
        plot1()
    })
    
    #Download
    downloaded <- reactiveVal(0)
    output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function() {
            return("Plot.png")
        },
        content = function(file) {
            png(file)
            print(plot1())
            dev.off()
            on.exit({spsComps::incRv(downloaded)})
        })
    #Write csv
    observeEvent(downloaded(), {
        dat <- as.data.frame(c(input$num_var_1, input$num_var_2))
        utils::write.csv(dat, "dat.csv", row.names = FALSE)
        print("File saved")
    }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

1. Unfortunately, you can't observe download event. So here we do, introduce another `reactiveVal` which we can change inside the download event so we will know if the download button has been clicked.
2. `spsComps::incRv` is a short hand function for `downloaded(isolate(downloaded()) + 1)`, so it increase the `reactiveVal` every time by one.
3. use `on.exit` on the end to make sure this happens only when the plot is successful.
4. Instead of using `eventReactive`, `observeEvent` should be used since you are not returning any value but just write a file.